# install JDK8 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, java-8

**I want to start programming in java and i am using ubuntu 14.04, i downlaoaed**

> jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz

**and in oracle website there is a command to install it, it is the command**

> % tar zxvf jdk-8uversion-linux-x64.tar.gz

**in terminal i got this**

> bash: fg: %: no such job

**anyone help me to intall the JDK.**

Comment: It is `tar zxvf jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz`, without the starting percent and with the correct version

Comment: Maybe you should learn some basic linux commands and/or linux shell before you start learning Java?

Answer (score 14):

Add the [webupd8](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) ppa, and install from that -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Then

```
java -version
```

should show you using Oracle Java 8. If not, or if you want to use a different version - run `update-java-alternatives` with something like,

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
```

or

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle
```

As appropriate.

Comment: Also consider to install oracle-java8-set-default: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Comment: Using this approach, it's also very easy to upgrade to a newer version when available.

Answer (score 0):

Debian way (whereas Ubuntu is Debian-baseD) of doing it is through packages.
So it is highly preferred to make a deb package.
Here is how:

```
sudo apt-get install java-package
make-jpkg jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo dpkg -i oracle-java8-jdk_8u20_amd64.deb
```

Maybe there is already some PPA already doing it for you, but better trust no-one and do it for yourself ;-)