# arduino ide does not start

Tags: arduino, rfduino

I'm new to arduino and trying to get IDE installed.
Both the 32 and 64 bit versions of Linux arduino IDE fail.
Thanks!

```
jay@jay-desktop $ bash arduino
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: processing/app/Base : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
```

java info

```
jay@jay-desktop $ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_95
jay@jay-desktop $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to run a version of the IDE that has been compiled for Java 1.8 on Java 1.7. Upgrading java to 1.8 ought to fix it.

Comment: using the answers from here got it started:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549492/install-jdk8-in-ubuntu-14-04